# Is the norm of an integral operator the essential supremum norm of its kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Is the following true?

Let $\mu$ be a probability measure and let $k\in L_\infty(\mu \otimes \mu)$. Define the operator $T_k\colon L_1(\mu)\to L_1(\mu)$ by $$(T_kf)(t) = \int k(t,x)f(x)\,\mu({\rm d}x).$$ Then $\|T_k\|=\|k\|_{L_\infty(\mu \otimes \mu)}$.

Comment: What techniques in the proofs you refer to make explicit use of the Lebesgue measure? I mean, can't you just use the same techniques here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that what you want a reference for is true. The estimate $\Vert T_k \Vert \leq \Vert K \Vert_{L^\infty}$ is trivial, but the other estimate fails in general, which can be seen as follows:

By Fubini,
\begin{align*}
&\Vert T_k f \Vert_{L^1} \\
&\leq  \int |f(x)| \int |k(t,x)| d\mu(t) d\mu(x) \\
& \leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^1} \cdot \mu-\mathrm{esssup}_x \int |k(t,x)| d\mu(t).
\end{align*}

Now consider on $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure the kernel
$$
k(t,x) = \frac{1}{x} \cdot 1_{t <x}.
$$
Then the integral from above satisfies
$$
\mu-\mathrm{esssup}_x \int |k(t,x)| d\mu(t)=1,
$$
but $\Vert k\Vert_{L^\infty} = \infty$.
I noticed that you require $k \in L^\infty$, but it should be easy to adapt my counterexample accordingly.

Comment: E.g., the simple kernel $k(t,x) = tx$ does it. So, it does not even hold for the Lebesgue measure (which OP actually claimed was true).